# Delete a row by index when no rows are matched

Tags: r

I want to delete a row of matrix `x` indexed by vector `k` such as

```
x = matrix(1:10, 5, 2)
k = rep(1, 5)

# my attempt:
index = which(k == 0)
y = x[-index, ]
#      [,1] [,2]
```

Here, no rows meet my condition for dropping, `k == 0`, so `index` will return the empty vector, `integer(0)`. Therefore, `x[-index, ]` will return a matrix with no lines instead of remaining itself.

I don't know how to handle this, please someone could help me on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delete rows in a data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328056/how-do-i-delete-rows-in-a-data-frame)

Comment: `y <- x[k != 0, ]`?

Comment: `if (length(index)==0) {y <- x} else {y <- x[-index]}`

Comment: @Axeman, when `k` is not present, it gives the expected behavior, but when `k` is present, it gives different output than `y <- x[-index]`, at least for me...

Comment: Perhaps you can make an actually working example then instead of pseudo code.

Comment: Yes, that's the risk when doing indexing like this. Better to stick with the raw condition (`k != 0`) than the possibly-zero-length vector of indices meeting it...

Answer (score 0):

The only complication could be k's size.
Otherwise this should solve it:
given x as:

```
  x=cbind(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

and

```
  k=c(1,2,0,1,0,2)
```

then

```
  x[!k==0,]
```