# Remove common values with one specific group

Tags: r

On a big dataset, I would like to delete the rows which present an id in common to the sample A. Then I would like to remove all the row from sample A.

```
 feature id sample
      a  1      A
      b  1      B
      c  2      A
      d  2      C
      e  3      A
      f  4      B
      g  4      C
      h  5      C
      i  5      C
```

The output should be:

```
 feature id sample
      f  4      B
      g  4      C
      h  5      C
      i  5      C
```

As my dataset as more than 8000 rows, I need another way to do it than saying row by row which one I want to delete.
I am not sure how to do that, any advice welcome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delete rows in a data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328056/how-do-i-delete-rows-in-a-data-frame)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to delete all the rows which has `id` same as the `id`s in "A", you could do

```
df[!df$id %in% df$id[df$sample == "A"], ]

#  feature id sample
#6       f  4      B
#7       g  4      C
#8       h  5      C
#9       i  5      C
```

Same with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  filter(!id %in% id[sample == "A"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R idea using `ave`,

```
with(dd, ave(sample, id, FUN = function(i)!'A' %in% i))
```

So to use it for indexing,

```
dd[as.logical(with(dd, ave(sample, id, FUN = function(i)!('A' %in% i)))),]
#  feature id sample
#6       f  4      B
#7       g  4      C
#8       h  5      C
#9       i  5      C
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `subset`

```
subset(df, !id %in% id[sample == "A"])
#    feature id sample
#6       f  4      B
#7       g  4      C
#8       h  5      C
#9       i  5      C
```