# Drop pandas row by name, keep index intact

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a dataframe from a csv file and I want to drop a certain row. I tried using `df2[df2.State != 'INDIA']`, where INDIA is the row I want to drop. Here's an example of the dataframe:

> ```
>                           State  Total population
> 10                      Gujarat          60383628
> 11                      Haryana          25353081
> 12             Himachal Pradesh           6856509
> 13                        INDIA        1210193422
> 14              Jammu & Kashmir          12548926
> 15                    Jharkhand          32966238
> 16                    Karnataka          61130704
> 17                       Kerala          33387677
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: There's no error but the change is not being reflected. It's still the exact same table. 
That worked @MohitMotwani. Is there any way to keep the index intact? 'INDIA'removed means that the index 13 is removed and hence the index is being displayed as 11, 12, 14, 15. Is this solvable?

Comment: You need to reassign it `df2=df2[df2.State != 'INDIA'] `

Comment: That worked @MohitMotwani. However, I still have a question. Is there any way to keep the index intact? INDIA removed means that the index 13 is removed and hence the index is being displayed as 11, 12, 14, 15. Is this solvable?

Comment: Use df2=df2. reset_index(drop=True) after the code

Comment: Cheers @anky_91. Worked for me

Comment: @Abhishek: please edit that second part of your question into the question above. Don't modify your question intent in comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possible way to drop the row while keeping the axis intact in one line could be:

```
df2 = df2.query("State != 'INDIA'")
```

Answer (score 2):

You should assign it to `df2`.

`df2 = df2[df2.State != 'INDIA']`

For more learning read [How do I delete rows in a data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328056/how-do-i-delete-rows-in-a-data-frame) as well.